# Getting the IOError while reading the file using Python

Tags: python

I am getting the following error while trying to read the file content using Python.

Error:

```
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/lampp/htdocs/Nuclear_reactor/d50/nuclear_vulnerable/2ceaebde4ca44cde963914c96b53c553.txt\r\n'
```

I am providing my code below:

```
param = request.POST.get('param')#2ceaebde4ca44cde963914c96b53c553.txt
test_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), param)
 f = open(test_file, 'r')
f.read()
f.close()
```

Here `.txt` file is present inside that folder but still its showing the error. Here I need to read that file.

Comment: Your filename has a Windows newline on the end, so I think you need to call `open(test_file.strip(), 'r')` instead.

Comment: @DanielLyons : Its working thanks but Can you sa how can I return those text file content to a html page(`lets say-'plant/home.html'`).

Comment: I don't understand your followup question.

Comment: @DanielLyons : I need to return the file content to that html page .

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the newline `\r\n` from the end of the file name, e.g. using string.strip()